# Excel VBA 2010 - worksheet.subtotal function sum and average in the same row

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am creating a macro which takes data from an Oracle database, which means that the number of rows can vary depending upon the result. In this macro, I am using the worksheet.subtotal function, which sums up on a number of columns when the group changes. This all works, but the problem that I am facing are that a few of the columns need to be average.

Searching around I have not been able to find a solution where you can have both average and sum in the same row. I do not wish to have a situation where the user has to manually intervene to change each column for each group.

Is there away where you can have both average and sum in the same row?

Comment: Andy, what do you mean that you are using `worksheet.subtotal function`? You should already know that adding code to your question significantly improve possibility of getting support here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot use both i.e `Sum` and `Average` together in `Subtotal` but don't loose heart :) Here is an alternative.

Let's say you have two columns. In one you want `Sum` and the other you want `Average`. In your code, set `Sum` for both columns. When the report is generated, simply highlight the column where you want `Average` and simply find and replace `subtotal(9` with `subtotal(1` using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> If you don't want to do it manually then you can do the `Find and Replace` in code as well ;)

This would work as `Sum` and `Average` have the same structure.

```
=Sum(<Range>)
=Average(<Range>)
```